Apache2 additional virtual host config not working
I have 3 domains  forwarded to my web server via DynDNS. The server has virtual host configs with the respective DocumentRoot, everything works fine.
I registered a 4th domain and also have it forwarded to the web server and a new host config. Unfortunately, the config does not work. The new domain is redirected to the wrong DocumentRoot. I have checked everything a thousand times, everything is correct. The config is enabled, syntax fits, no errors in the logs.
Maybe someone else has a tip for me?

Simplest things first - have you restarted Apache? Config files are only read at service start.

Perhaps you could share with us your configuration?

Yes, I've restart apache after each editing

This is the new config:
<VirtualHost *:80 [::]:80>
    ServerName kleinanzeigen-archiv.org
    ServerAlias www.kleinanzeigen-archiv.org
    DocumentRoot /home/gs-cloud/projects/kleinanzeigen/dist
    <Directory /home/gs-cloud/projects/kleinanzeigen/dist>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/kleinanzeigen-archiv.org-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/kleinanzeigen-archiv.de-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

But it will redirect to:
<VirtualHost *:80 [::]:80>
    ServerName gartenbau-domain.de
    ServerAlias www.gartenbau-domain.de
    DocumentRoot /home/gs-cloud/projects/gartenbau
    <Directory /home/gs-cloud/projects/gartenbau>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gartenbau-domain.de-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gartenbau-domain.de-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Meanwhile i found a different solution, but not on my server. I'm still interesst on a solution on my server.
I've changed the sequence of configs with renameming to 000-new-domain.conf, but this aint helping as well. All default config has been disabled.
